# Retrieve Values of Label Depending on CheckBox State

Tags: javascript, html

How would you retrieve the values of a Label corresponding to a checkbox in HTML? I have two/three labels and a checkbox next to each other now i need to retrieve the value of the labels if the checkbox is checked. Could you let me know how to achieve this? In the example below i want to retrieve the two text strings within the labels when the checkbox is checked. I need to know how to connect the checkbox with labels or something like this since there will be about 100 checkboxes with about 200 Labels so i need a way to connect Lables to checkboxes??

```
<label>Value:13485894033</label>  
<label>Custom Asset Type </label> 
<input type="checkbox" name="CB1" value="CSElement;1242632775392" id="checkbox1"  />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "value of the labels" ?

Comment: I want to retrieve the string that appears in the label.

Comment: What string appears in the label? I see an label and an input thats it.

Comment: May be you should create some jsFiddle ?

Comment: I am not very familiar with front end development but ill research this

Comment: You shall not put input inside label, instead write input next to the label

Comment: Edited the question now to reflect my thoughts

Comment: @CodeGeek123 Are you willing to use jquery?

Comment: Well Id like a solution without using JQuery but if i must i will. Simply because all i want to do is retrieve these values and process them in java so i dont want to do anything complex.

Comment: You don't HAVE TO but jquery would make this a lot easier. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you are after.

Sample HTML:

```
<input id="check1" type="checkbox" class="watchFor" />
<label for="check1" >First Checkbox</label><br />


<input id="check2" type="checkbox"  class="watchFor" />
<label for="check2" >Second Checkbox</label>
```

And then the jquery:

```
$(function(){
$(".watchFor").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
          var id = $(this).attr("id");
          var label = $("label[for='" + id + "']");
          alert(label.text());
       }
   });
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LwPrM/

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class name to labels corresponding to checkbox id

```
<label class="checkbox1">Value:13485894033</label>  
<label class="checkbox1">Custom Asset Type </label> 
<input type="checkbox" name="CB1" value="CSElement;1242632775392" id="checkbox1"  />

var labels = document.getElementByTagsName("label");

for(var i=0;i<labels.length;i++)
{
   if(document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked)
   {
      if(labels[i].class == "checkbox1")
         var string = labels[i].innerHTML;
   }
}
```